# How to get mac address from integrated network adapter

Tags: java, windows, mac-address, serial-number

Many motherboards have an integrated network adapter. I need to get mac address from this device if exists.
From Network adapter:

```
private void getMacFromInetAddress(){
    try {

            Enumeration<NetworkInterface> networks = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
            while (networks.hasMoreElements()) {
                NetworkInterface network = networks.nextElement();
                byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

                if (mac != null) {
                    System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                        sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
                    }
                }
           }
        } catch (UnknownHostException | SocketException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
}
```

how to get specify the name of a integrated network adapter from this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
System.out.println("Current IP address : " + ip.getHostAddress());

NetworkInterface network = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(ip);

byte[] mac = network.getHardwareAddress();

System.out.print("Current MAC address : ");

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
    sb.append(String.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : ""));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

and to get the hardware info u can use wmic commands like 
**wmic cpu get ProcessorId**

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic cpu get ProcessorId");
            String procesSerial=
                    new BufferedReader
                            (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream())).[ReadSecondLine];
```

and bios

**wmic bios get SerialNumber**

```
 Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic bios get SerialNumber");
```

Comment: you can even get the list of ethernet adapters/Mac address if you want

Comment: friend, here and mac address virtual network adapters, too, gives 

and then will be the same mac addresses on multiple machine

Comment: @Saahon Then create a combo String like 
CPUID+"|"+BIOSSerial+"|"+MAC
so then duplication will be minimised.
if you want to read hardware info, it is no more platform independent. 
Thanks.

Comment: Nope yar, no need to copy for such simple question,, if its useful upote

Answer (score 1):

> How to get mac address from device?

There is no direct way to get `mac address` from system through `Java`. But you can

To get mac addresses on the computer, Just run the command `getmac` to get the mac addresses.[image]

2. Use `ipconfig` command to deal with this.
3. Retrieve the mac addressses for a remote computer using `nbtstat` command.
4. Run the `getmac` and `getmac /s remote_computer /u username /p password` command to retrieve the mac addresses of a remote computer.

[Get mac address from command line](https://www.windows-commandline.com/get-mac-address-command-line/)

But through ***Java*** you need to use `Java exec system with Java ProcessBuilder and Process`

For example:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("getmac");
//Map<String, String> env = pb.environment(); //set env
pb.directory("C\\");
Process p = pb.start();
```

**or**

```
// build my command as a list of strings
//@@@ For Unix/Linux
List<String> command = new ArrayList<String>();
command.add("getmac");

// execute my command
SystemCommandExecutor commandExecutor = new SystemCommandExecutor(command);
int result = commandExecutor.executeCommand();
```

**Then read output through:**

```
// get the output from the command
StringBuilder stdout = commandExecutor.getStandardOutputFromCommand();
StringBuilder stderr = commandExecutor.getStandardErrorFromCommand();

// print the output from the command
System.out.println("STDOUT");
System.out.println(stdout);
System.out.println("STDERR");
System.out.println(stderr);
```

[ProcessBuilder and Process Code](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1)

*`Note:` Your `java application` need `administrative permission during execution`.*

Answer (score 0):

Use the UUID with some changes

1st time it runs, generate a unique UUID and SAVE it in local storage. From 2nd time onwards use the saved UUID from 1st run.

Comment: let's say this: my program for each machine gives only one unique key. If I generate uuid and save it local storage, then the client will copy this program with local storage and put it on another machine instead of with a local key ....

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to look at the [oshi library](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) to get system OS/hardware information.

Look at the [test case](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oshi/oshi/master/oshi-core/src/test/java/oshi/SystemInfoTest.java) for the example.

Below is the truncated output on my system.

```
Microsoft Windows 7 SP1 build 7601
manufacturer: LENOVO
model: 20AWA0MAIN
serialnumber: PB01FEYL
baseboard:
  manufacturer: LENOVO
  serialnumber: L1HF43B026Z               
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600M CPU @ 2.90GHz
 2 physical CPU(s)
 4 logical CPU(s)
Identifier: Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3
ProcessorID: BFEBFBFF000306C3
Memory: 9.2 GiB/15.7 GiB
Swap used: 0 bytes/15.7 GiB
Uptime: 0 days, 04:24:20
Disks:
 \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0: (model: HGST HTS725050A7E6300 SCSI Disk Device (Standard disk drives) - S/N:       TF655AWH2RKE6L) size: 500.1 GB, reads: 325475 (7.1 GiB), writes: 306825 (4.4 GiB), xfer: 12447064 ms
 |-- Disk #0, Partition #0: Installable File System (Installable File System) Maj:Min=0:0, size: 104.9 MB
Network interfaces:
 Name: eth8 (Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM)
   MAC Address: 28:d2:44:68:40:23 
   MTU: 1500, Speed: 0 bps 
   IPv4: [] 
   IPv6: [fe80:0:0:0:553d:8bc9:6a95:236e] 
   Traffic: received ?/?; transmitted ?/? 
 Name: wlan9 (Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260)
   MAC Address: 7c:7a:91:37:cb:f7 
   MTU: 1500, Speed: 130 Mbps 
   IPv4: [192.168.1.66] 
   IPv6: [fe80:0:0:0:55e0:97b3:f282:4c06] 
   Traffic: received 121644 packets/114.0 MiB (0 err); transmitted 90086 packets/12.7 MiB (0 err) 
Displays:
 Display 0:
  Manuf. ID=LEN, Product ID=40a0, Analog, Serial=00000000, ManufDate=1/2012, EDID v1.4
  31 x 17 cm (12.2 x 6.7 in)
  Preferred Timing: Clock 72MHz, Active Pixels 2656x768 
  Preferred Timing: Clock 63MHz, Active Pixels 2656x768 
  Manufacturer Data: 0000000F008C09328C093214090006AF3C33
  Unspecified Text: B140XTN03.3
```